# implementing socket.io in nodeJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am building a project in which i have to add,update and delete users. Currently they are showing like this :

[image]

Now i wanna make my application real-time. So i am using socket.io in order to work with websockets. I made a connection between server and all clients, they are connected successfully. Then every time a user is deleted or updated, i emit a event and run that on server using socket.io (socket.emit --- socket.on) and in response i send complete collection back to client. Then on client side i am loading the response back to `$scope`

```
$http.post('/getUserInfo', Obj)

            .then(function(response) {
                if (response) {

                    //console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.users = response.data;
                }
            });
```

But there is a glitch in this process because angularJS change the complete object `$scope.users` instead of just the change. Anybody suggest me how to solve this problem  ? How to make this process smooth and also the data (`response.data`) is too big, so it is taking a lot of time.

Comment: first in view call this method, with object repeated item, second, response data only of current user, this is what you are expecting

Comment: Actually what i wanna do is to just update the only use i clicked on instead of disturbing the complete object `$scope.users`. means if i delete one user then that user will delete from that client and also all other clients are updated with new data.

Comment: then you need to pass to method the current item from repeater in view. That your are doing?

Comment: yes i am passing that item but the problem is how to remove that item from all other users

Comment: delete from array of users, then the repeater in view will digest and remove alone

Comment: I think each item will have id take that id for removing and also adding it to the $scope.users.. so how, store the element position(index) and after the success response remove or add that particular element depending on the index which you have saved earlier.